# show date and time for RadDatePicker

Tags: telerik

I am using telerik q1 2010 radcontrols. I want to show both Date and Time in RadDatePicker
. PLease suggest me what should I do.

Answer (score 4):

Use [RadDateTimePicker](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/calendar/examples/datetimepicker/autopostbackcontrol/defaultcs.aspx) for this purpose.

Comment: But this is available in telerik q2 2010 that I don't want to use.

Comment: The date time picker is available since the first Telerik AJAX release.